# Location problems in react native like cached location

Tags: react-native, gps, location

I have developed a React Native Application that record working hours and location where the user can send the location they are and the hour when they did it.

It works fine but I have notified me by a few users  that in few cases the app doesn't registry the location expected. Like they have signed from they house but the mobile phone was in the work at the moment of the signed.

Avoiding if the user is lying or doesn't, there is a possibility of the device could be caching location by itself?

I mean, I know that isn't an app problem due to the app is very simple and it only ask for the location to the device. In the case that the location could be bad taken, there is a way to clean the cache from the location of the device?

Comment: This is the same question as the last question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is a way to avoid navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition from be cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656908/there-is-a-way-to-avoid-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-from-be-cached)