# There is a way to avoid navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition from be cached?

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching, location

I'm using in my React Native App the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function to get the location of  my device but I have been reading that sometimes if the function notes that you have no good signal it could return the cached location. There is a way to avoid the returning cached location and return an error instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

The problem was that I wasn't passing the timeout time to the options and then the device was trying to get the location immediately, so it wouldn't be able to do that and was getting from the cache.

Now it is getting like 3 seconds to get the location but works fine!

Answer (score 1):

> geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, [geo_error],
>   [geo_options]);

Use the option value in the function. You can use `maximumAge`

- `maximumAge(ms)`-positive value representing the maximum life in
  milliseconds of a reversible cache location. If set to 0, it means
  that the device cannot use the cached location and must actually
  retrieve the current location. When set to `Infinity`, the device
  always returns a cached position, regardless of its lifetime. The
  default is `INFINITY`.

```js
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true, // true: use GPS false : WIFI 
  maximumAge: 0 // default Infinity
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};
```

Comment: It didn't fix the problem. While you are right what you are say, I was doing the same and wasn't working. I found the key and was that, in addition of the maximumAge, I had to add timeout time, due to if I didn't do the device won't get a right location with no age. For that reason I had to put maximumAge = 0 and timeout 15000. Thank you for the response anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. 
First location from
**navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onLocationFound, onLocationError, {maximumAge:60000, timeout:12000, enableHighAccuracy:true});**
was to old. 
Compare e.timestamp and current timestamp

```
now = new Date(); 
if((now - e.timestamp)<10000){ //OK if less than 10 sek (10000ms) 
//YES, new location
//stop updating navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(window.watchId);
}
else
{ 
//old lacation, wait 
}
```